# Flash security panel text grabled

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm trying to create a hidden swf that manages the microphone it's 1 pixel. When it comes time to request the permission I expand the swf to the size of the page however the text for the security popup comes up garbled. Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve the text issue?

[image]

Comment: But why you don't show your swf with a normal size (which can show the security panel) and the resize it to 1px?

Comment: Is this happening all the time, or only when you rescale from a 1px  swf? If it's a question of rescale, you might be better off simply hiding and showing the swf using Javascript